# Mock IDbDataAdapter Fill Method With Moq

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

I have an object that reads data from an Excel file using, which takes a `IDbConnection`, `IDbDataAdapter` and an `IDbCommand`. I use the adapters fill method to populate a table with data, and this is how I am currently mocking it:

```
[TestCase]
public void TestReadCellsFromSpreadsheetReadsSuccessfully()
{
    var cells = new List<ReportData>
                    {
                        new ReportData { CellId = 1, ExcelCellLocation = "A1"},
                        new ReportData { CellId = 2, ExcelCellLocation = "A2"},
                        new ReportData { CellId = 3, ExcelCellLocation = "A3"},
                        new ReportData { CellId = 4, ExcelCellLocation = "A4"}
                    };

    _mockAdapter.Setup(a => a.Fill(It.IsAny<DataSet>()))
        .Callback((DataSet ds) =>
                      {
                          if (ds.Tables["Table"] == null)
                          {
                              ds.Tables.Add("Table");
                              ds.Tables["Table"].Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                          }

                          var row = ds.Tables["Table"].NewRow();
                          row[0] = "Test";

                          ds.Tables["Table"].Rows.Add(row);
                      });

    var excelReader = new ExcelReader(_mockConnection.Object, _mockAdapter.Object, _mockCommand.Object);
    excelReader.ReadCellsFromSpreadsheet("Deal Summary", cells);

    _mockCommand.VerifySet(c => c.CommandText = It.IsAny<string>(), Times.Exactly(cells.Count));
    _mockAdapter.VerifySet(a => a.SelectCommand = _mockCommand.Object, Times.Exactly(cells.Count));
    _mockAdapter.Verify(a => a.Fill(It.IsAny<DataSet>()), Times.Exactly(cells.Count));
}
```

This implementation works, but I feel like I'm doing too much to Mock the adapter... is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not pass those 3 objects as parameters. Instead pass IDataReader, IDataProvider or sth like that that returns data. Then You just mock this object. And you don't need reference to System.Data in project containing ExcellReader.

And two other things I don't like about your code.
Why TestCase instead of Test?

Are you sure you want to create command and fill dataset for each column separately? (but maybe I don't understand your code)

Comment: `[TestCase]` is for NUnit, `[Test]` is for the Visual Studio tests. Also, I am creating a command for each column seperately because I am selecting specific cells based on a mapping. The data isn't tabular therefore I have to take individual cells.

Comment: Not true. [Test] is for NUnit. [TestCase] is parameterized test in NUnit. But you don't pass any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I have some rules about data access:

1. Write a simple class that wraps all the data access logic, so that other classes don't have to deal with DataAdapters and all that crap.
2. When you write unit tests, don't mock out DataAdapters; instead just mock out the wrapper classes that you just created.
3. Make the data access wrapper logic so simple that it doesn't really need to be unit tested. If it DOES need to be tested, then write integration tests that hit a small sample database.